# Adding a new field depending on the condition in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have five fields in a Query named Status. Lets consider the names of the fields for an easy demonstration as A,B,C,D,E. The Status Query looks something like this

```
A         B           C           D            E
1         a                                    d
2                     n           o            
3         t           z   
4         r           m           d            
          q           f           j
```

I am looking to add a field to the above Query named Description which looks through each record and adds a description. For example if the field A is empty then in the description it must show Failed A. if the field B is empty then it must show Failed B and in the similar way Failed C, Failed D and Failed E. There may also be multiple Fields which are empty for a record. But it must describe which field is empty first for that record. It must show something like this :

```
A         B           C           D            E        Description
1         a                                    d          Failed C
2                     n           o                       Failed B
3         t           z                                   Failed D
4         r           m           d                       Failed E
          q           f           j                       Failed A
```

I have tried to use IIF function in the following way

```
IIF(A is null,Failed A,IIF(B is null),Failed B, IIF(C is null), Failed C,IIF(D is null), Failed D,Failed E)
```

It doesn't work in this way. How Can I achieve the above? Or where am I going wrong in the code?

Comment: By looking at your previous questions, I have the feeling that you are misusing this platform to get quick solutions for your problems rather than understanding the fundamentals of coding and asking specific questions.  VBA has big community and above question been asked many times, yet you don't Google but ask two times about iif within one day because you get solutions but don't grasp the technical aspect behind it. Coding is fun but you are cheating yourself with this game. I'm not picking up on you. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this:

```
"Failed " & IIF(A is null,"A",IIF(B is null),"B", IIF(C is null), "C",IIF(D is null), "D","E")
```

Comment: when I use "Failed " & IIF(A is null,"A",IIF(B is null),"B", IIF(C is null), "C",IIF(D is null), "D","E") As Description. It gives me Wrong number of Arguments used with function in query expression error.

Comment: Yes, all the closing parenthesis are missing.

Comment: Yup! My bad! Thanks